# Simplest Visual Studio That Supports C# and F#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, f#

What is the simplest version of Visual Studio (professional, enterprise, or other) that I could purchase that supports C# or F# development?

It looks like F# is downloadable from Microsoft for no charge and comes in configurations
that would allow .Net and non-.Net development with or without Visual Studio. Am I missing something?

Is the same true for C#? That is is it downloadable without cost?

Thank you.

Comment: Many thanks to all. These were great answers.

Comment: I know you ask specifically about VS, but I believe that SharpDevelop supports both C# and F# (never tried though, just read about it somewhere)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C# is downloadable without cost as either part of the Windows SDK (which provides a commandline compiler `csc`) or Visual C# Express, which provides an IDE.

F# is available either in commandline form (`fsc`) or as a Visual Studio plugin, which requires the VS Shell (which is freely downloadable) or a full (non-Express) Visual Studio.

This means that you must purchase at least VS Professional to open both types of projects in the same editor, but you could also use a combination of VS Express and VS Shell for free.

Answer (score 10):

The simplest single version of Visual Studio which supports both developing in F# and C# is professional.

It's possible to install multiple free versions of the Visual Studio shell to allow you to develop C# and F# locally

- C# via [Express SKU](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-csharp-express)
- F# via [Free Tools + Isolated Shell](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2010/08/17/announcing-the-f-2-0-free-tools-for-net-4-0.aspx)

This won't give you a single IDE though for developing in both languages.

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio Express Editions allows you to develop in NET languages. For example Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express and it has no cost.

However it lacks many features. If you need a more powerful IDE, you can use SharpDevelop. It has no cost and allow you to develop in C#, F# and many more. Give it a try. Good luck!